Can retired UK citizen expat top up NI payments and claim State Pension?
I am a UK citizen.  I lived in UK from 1960 to 1985.  From 1978 to 1985 I had a full-time job and paid all the required taxes including National Insurance.  (The names of various taxes and benefits have probably changed since I last knew them.)  Now I am 69.  My questions are:

Can I make some kind of payment to top up my contributions to a level that would qualify me to receive the State Pension (I'm referring to what used to be called the old age pension - paid by the government to the person and financed in part by a tax on wage-earners' earnings.)
Having done that, can I claim and receive the state pension (OAP)?

I ask because I met a person on a plane who told me a friend of his had recently retired, made a payment, and, although living in US for a long time and still living in US, receives his UK state pension.  That person told me he thought the government had taken away the rights to do this.
This question As a British ex-pat living in the USA, should I top up my NI contributions? does not answer my question.
I live in US and have done so for quite a while.
thanks for any help.

Where do you live now? That could make a difference as the rules for paying UK pensions abroad can vary by country.

According to this page, one reason to top up is:

you live outside the UK, but you want to qualify for certain benefits or the State Pension

So the basic answer seems likely to be "yes".
In addition, if you act quickly, it looks like you could pay for about 18 years:

If you want to make voluntary contributions for the tax years 2016 to 2017 or 2017 to 2018, the deadline has been extended. You have until 5 April 2025 to pay.

[...]

[If] you’re a man born after 5 April 1951 or a woman born after 5 April 1953
You have until 5 April 2025 to pay voluntary contributions to make up for gaps between tax years April 2006 and April 2016 if you’re eligible.

You'll need to work out what it costs against the state pension it gives you. Bear in mind that in some countries the pension will not be uprated for inflation, though from your profile you live in the USA and it will be there.

Not only is this possible, but it's the best financial deal you will ever get.  A hundred pounds or so will buy you an extra year's contributions which will get you more than a hundred pounds every year of your pension.

@GS - Apologise to Monica  Thanks so much for this.  It's exactly what I need.  And, "Yes, I live in US."  I'll edit question to make that clear.
